# How to pass the parameter from view to controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I am new to Rails and I am working on a simple application for "tasklist" (To do list).

In my app, I want to categories the tasks based different type of category(shopping, todo - user can create own category). So I created separate model for `User`, `Category` and `Task` and each `Task` is linked with one `category`.

In my view (`users/show.html.erb` -n side this I render view for `category` and `task`), I have listed all the categories in left side and all the open tasks in right side. I want to make categories as LINKS, so when user select one categories, only the tasks which is linked to that category type will get displayed in the right side.

I understand how a normal link_to works when it takes to a new page. I also understand how button works in bootstrap. But I am not able to identify how I can pass the category selection into the controller, so I can pull only the task where the category matches with what user selected.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `category` parameter to some sort of evaluation function, filtering the appropriate categories. This can either be done with `Javascript` or `Rails`:

**Rails**

```
<% Category.all.each do |category| %>
  <%= link_to category.name, users_path(user, category: category.id) %>
<% end %>
```

This will pass a `category` param to your `users#show` action:

```
def show
  @user = User.find params[:id]
  @categories = @user.categories
  @categories = @categories.where(category: params[:category]) if params[:category]
end
```

---

**Javascript**

If you wanted to be explorative, you'd want to use JS to keep your functionality on this view only:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "a.category", function(e){
  var id = $(this).data("category_id");
  $(".todos a").not("[data-category_id=\"" + id + \""]").hide();
});

#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<% Category.all.each do |category| %>
  <%= link_to category.name, users_path(user, category: category.id), class: "category", data: { category_id: category.id } %>
<% end %>

<div class="todos">
  <% @user.todos.each do |todo| %>
    <%= link_to todo.title, todo, data: { category_id: todo.category_id } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This will allow you to click a "category" and have the list of "todos" change to suit.

Comment: I tried the Rails code and when I click     category link control is taking me to     index action instead of     show action

Comment: Can you show me the console log for the request please?

Comment: I guess I have given the wrong path in the link_to, which causes the issue. Now I corrected the link_to to point to user_path and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `category` in your `link_to` like this:

```
link_to "Task for test_category", task_path(category: "test_category")
```

Then, you can grab the category using `params[:category]` inside your controller and use it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should create a new route instead of passing parameter.

```
resources(:categories) do 
  member do
   get(:linked_tasks)
  end
end
```

And in categories controller

```
def linked_tasks
  category = Category.find(params[:id])
  tasks = category.tasks.where(is_linked: true)
end
```

Hope this will help you.